# Update child record when parent record is created - possible w/ process builder?

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, lookup, child-to-parent

I could not find any info online on whether or not is possible to update a parent record when a child record is created in a lookup relationship in process builder or if it would have to be a trigger. The parent object is `recurring_donation__c` and the child is `Opportunity` The logic is as follows:

```
1. For each recurring donation created:
2.   Update opportunity stage from pledged to posted
```

The related opportunity record does not appear when selecting a record related to the object in process builder as `recurring donation` does not have a field for opportunity, it is only the parent

Thanks in advance

Comment: "whether or not is possible to update a parent record when a child record is created" -> 

It sounds like you actually want to do the opposite of this, update a child record (opportunity) when a parent record (recurring_donation__c) is created. Technically this is not possible through any means, because a parent record has to exist before a lookup on the child can be populated with its id.

So correct me if I'm misunderstanding; it sounds like you're looking to update the opportunity stage when the opportunity's recurring_donation__c lookup is populated. Is it more complicated than that?

Comment: @NathanaelSchmolze You are correct. Currently we have recurring donations that create opportunities automatically but the stage is set to 'pledged' and we need it to automatically set to posted as long as the close date is before the current date. Are there any workarounds for this with other tools?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please [edit] your post to clarify if you are using Nonprofit Success Pack (NPSP), the Legacy or Enhanced Recurring Donation feature, and if your recurring donations payment processor (stripe, authorize.net, etc) is integrated with Salesforce.

Comment: Also - the best support resource for NPSP is the [Salesforce Power of Us Hub](https://powerofus.force.com/s/), where you'll find discussion groups for a wide range of areas.  The participants are other NPSP users, consultants, and Salesforce.org staff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given our back-and-forth in the comments, it sounds like all of this can happen in an opportunity process builder, without any cross-object updates.

1. Create an opportunity record update process
2. In the first diamond, place the following formula: NOT(ISBLANK(recurring_donation__c)) && CloseDate < TODAY()
3. In the list of actions, add an action to update the record that started this process (the opportunity)
4. Set the StageName field to update to 'pledged'
5. Save and activate the process

Notably, there is now a tool that is being promoted by Salesforce over process builder. PB can be highly inefficient due to the way it performs record updates; the recommended tool is now record-trigger flows, as it runs about 10 times faster than even workflow rules:

https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/trigger-automation/

This tool has some drawbacks, in that it's still new, and doesn't support all of the features that process builder supports. But for any new automation you build, I'd recommend trying to implement it through record-trigger flows first, then fall back to PB or workflow rules if you can't.

Comment: Thanks! I got confused with the logic - it was actually for each OPPORTUNITY created that is related to a recurring donation - update the opportunity stage to posted

Comment: No problem! ~ Nate